# RxSwift Disposing one subscription invokes dispose of another subscription

Tags: rx-swift, subscription

I have a `PublishSubject<InfoData>` in a ViewController. And I subscribe to it, so when it emits an event - I show the UIAlertViewController.

```
let infoData = PublishSubject<InfoData>()
private func bindInfoData() {
     infoData.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (title, message) in
         self?.presentInfoSheetController(with: title, message: message)
     }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

In a ViewController I have a tableView with section headers. Section header view has a `infoMessageAction: PublishSubject<InfoData?>`. When initiating a view for `viewForHeaderInSection` I make a subscription between the `infoMessageAction` and `infoData`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      let view = FutureSpendingsHeaderView(frame: frame)
      view.infoMessageAction
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .bind(to: infoData)
            .disposed(by: view.disposeBag)
      return view
}
```

When the header view initiated for the first time all works good - `infoMessageAction` triggers the `infoData` which in turn triggers presentation of AlertViewController.
When I scroll header view beyond the screen the subscription between `view.infoMessageAction` and `infoData` disposes (which is expected behavior as the view was deinited).

But I get disposed the subscription between `infoData` and ViewController as well. I receive `event completed` and `dispose` for `view.infoMessageAction` <-> `infoData` subscription and also `event completed` and `dispose` for `infoData` <-> ViewController subscription.

I expect that only `view.infoMessageAction` <-> `infoData` subscription should break. Also both subscriptions disposed by different disposeBag. Why is `infoData` <-> ViewController subscription get disposed and how to prevent it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `FutureSpendingsHeaderView` is deinitialized, whatever view that is the source of `infoMessageAction` is also being deinitialized, and that view emits a `completed` event at that time. That completed event is passed on to `infoData` which then emits its own completed event.

Once an Observable has emitted a completed event, it is done. It can't emit any more events. So the subscription to it is disposed.

Your answer @Alex changes the equation by changing the order that things inside your view get deinitialized. The disposeBag is getting deinitialized first now, which breaks the observable chain before the view sends the completed event.

A better solution would be to use a `PublishRelay` rather than a `PublishSubject`. Relays don't emit completed events.

Even better than that would be to get rid of the subject entirely and do something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = FutureSpendingsHeaderView(frame: frame)
    view.infoMessageAction
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (title, message) in
            self?.presentInfoSheetController(with: title, message: message)
        })
        .disposed(by: view.disposeBag)
    return view
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `PublishRelay` fixed everything. Solution to bind directly doesn't work as I have other observables binded to `infoData`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, if anyone faces such situation.
In section header view I initiated `disposeBag` as constant and thought that everything else is handled by RxSwift itself when the view is deinited.
So I updated the view to:

```
var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
deinit {
    disposeBag = DisposeBag()
}
```

Now the subscription get disposed as needed.